# Passing Matrix block to a macro

Tags: matrix, switch

I want to fetch a specific block from a Matrix global then pass it through a macro which returns a response based on the block type. However, if I try to use `slice` the type doesn't appear to be available to the macro. Has anyone experienced something similar?

eg if I set `{% set timelineText = timeline.timeline %}` (where first `timeinline` is my global and second `timeline` is my Matrix field) then fetch a specific block from the Matrix: `{% set period = timelineText|slice(0,1) %}` should return the first instance/block from the field. I can then pass this to my macro: `{{ _self.doPeriod(period) }}`

My macro is

````
{% macro doPeriod(content) %}
{% switch content.type %}
{% case 'quote' %}
    ...
{% case 'period' %}
    ...
{% endswitch %}    
{% endmacro %}```
````

But this returns the following error: `Key "type" for array with keys "0" does not exist`

Any thoughts?

Comment: To add some more detail, if I dump contents of, eg `timelineText|slice(0,1)` all the Matrix blocks are returned. However, if I do `timelineText.first` only the first block is returned. 

Is `slice` the right filter in this instance/for this use?

Comment: Okay, if my initial request just fetches the ids then this works as I can fetch specific blocks via an id() request, eg:

`{% set timelineIds = timeline.timeline.ids() %}`. Then
`{% set period = timeline.timeline.id(timelineIds[0:1]).first %}` with `{{ _self.doPeriod(period) }}`

However, this does mean a new DB request for each block which seems a bit excessive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to import your macro, and not just call `{{ _self.doPeriod() }}`. [From the documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/1.x/tags/macro.html):

> When you define a macro in the template where you are going to use it, you might be tempted to call the macro directly via _self.input() instead of importing it; even if seems to work, this is just a side-effect of the current implementation and it won't work anymore in Twig 2.x.

I always do: `{% import _self as self %}`

[slice](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/slice.html) returns a sequence - in your case an array with one element, and the key is `0`. Your macro is expecting a matrix block, not an array, which is why you get that error.

If you only want the first block, then `{% set period = timelineText.first %}` and `period` will be a matrix block. `{{ self.doPeriod(period) }}` will work.

If you want to call `doPeriod` on all of the matrix blocks, then:

```
{% for period in timelineText %}
  ... {{ self.doPeriod(period) }} ...
{% endfor %}
```